# Insulation and vapor barriers behind Corian/Greenboard shower walls

Tags: drywall, insulation, shower, vapor-barrier

I've got a small bathroom that I am working on repairing/refinishing.

I've removed the existing (leaky) shower and base and am replacing them with Corian-like materials (Kohler's Choreograph for the walls and Avonite for the base).

One wall is on an exterior wall of the house. The other is indoors facing the living room.

The insulation I'd like to install (UltraTouch Denim) is unfaced. Do I need to put some poly up to serve as a vapor barrier behind the Greenboard that is going to go behind the walls, or is the Greenboard/Choreograph going to combine with it to form a moisture sandwich?

I'm in Southern Wisconsin, so we get cold winters and hot, humid summers (though I suppose the shower will provide more moisture than anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a local kitchen/bath remodeling company, current code recently changed in my area to specify *no* vapor barrier behind the solid-surface install.